# Error in Android Toolbar

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, toolbar

I am using toolbar in android which works fine in lollipop version but unfortunately it doesn't works in older versions.

Toolbar xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar                                                               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Java class:

```
public class MainAct extends AppCompatActivity{
Toolbar mtoolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.act_main);
    mtoolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar);

}
```

Styles:

```
<resources>
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "nidhinkumar.reccs"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}  
  }dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    }
```

I have tried changing the style to No action bar but still the app doesn't runs on the older device and i am getting the following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nidhinkumar.reccs/nidhinkumar.reccs.MainAct}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:816)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
        at nidhinkumar.reccs.MainAct.onCreate(MainAct.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5286)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
```

Comment: Have you added "compile 'com.android.support:design:YOUR VERSION' " on your gradle? 

Also you need to set NoActionBar theme of that activity from manifest

Comment: do you have another values folder like `values-14` or `values-11`? if yes remove it or open style.xml from that folder and change its parent theme to `NoActioBar`.

Comment: no i don't have any folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this not so sure may be because of your compileSdkVersion is higher,
change compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1' to

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

if this does not work, change your build.gradle(Project) classPath 
to a lower varsion(say 1.3.0 or 1.3.1)
```

Comment: if is was the appcompat that was the issue, you need to update your studio to that version before you can use the dependencies. which is still the same reason for the classPath, i had an issue of such, which was resolved when i updated by studio. I guess every thing in studio dependencies are align with it classPath. Navigate to this link if you what to know more https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your xml file:

```
<include
android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
layout="@layout/actionbar_main"></include>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
```

To :

```
android:minHeight="@dimen/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
```

- These libraries offer backward-compatible versions of new features,
  provide useful UI elements that are not included in the framework. So
  for devices below Lollipop these features are not included. So these
  support libraries makes things possible for versions below Lollipop.